# Why does the kinematic body move in opposite direction after I interpolate its movement, and how do I fix it?

Tags: godot, interpolation

I have added some basic movement and some manual interpolation to a cube that is a kinematic body in Godot.

```
extends KinematicBody

var speed : int = 10
var slowdown_buffer = 0.2
var movement = Vector3(0,0,0)
func _ready():
    pass
    
func interpolate():
    if movement.x > 0:
            movement.x -= slowdown_buffer
    elif movement.x < 0:
        movement.x += slowdown_buffer
    else:
        movement.x = 0.0
func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        movement.x = -speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        movement.x = speed
    else: 
        interpolate()
        
    move_and_slide(movement)
```

The problem is that when I move the cube using `A` and `D`, after the cube stops after the interpolation, it starts moving in the opposite direction with a non-increasing speed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: there's a more simple way to do it, I forgot how, but to learn more go to Coding With tom youtube channel for a simple KinematicBody Movement/meshes/FPS/InvetorySyetem/RayCast Weapon System. (I Also Suggest GarbajYT)

Answer (score 5):

You can't rely on `movement.x` hitting 0. This is because floating point errors. Instead, check if it is closer to 0 than `slowdown_buffer` then set it to 0. Like so:

```
extends KinematicBody

var speed : int = 10
var slowdown_buffer = 0.2
var movement = Vector3(0,0,0)
func _ready():
    pass
    
func interpolate():
    var slowdown = slowdown_buffer
    if movement.x > 0:
        if movement.x < slowdown:
            movement.x = 0
        else:
            movement.x -= slowdown
    elif movement.x < 0:
        if movement.x > -slowdown:
            movement.x = 0
        else:
            movement.x += slowdown

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        movement.x = -speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        movement.x = speed
    else: 
        interpolate()
        
    move_and_slide(movement)
```

Another thing I notice is that you are not using `delta`. And thus your code is not compensating variations in frame rate.

I would pass it to `interpolate`, and have `slowdown = slowdown_buffer * delta`. The units of `slowdown_buffer` were in change of speed per frame, after they are in change of speed per second. Assuming you had a target frame rate of 60, you want to multiply `slowdown_buffer` by 60, which gives us the value 12.

Like this:

```
extends KinematicBody

var speed : int = 10
var slowdown_buffer = 12
var movement = Vector3(0,0,0)
func _ready():
    pass
    
func interpolate(delta):
    var slowdown = slowdown_buffer * delta
    if movement.x > 0:
        if movement.x < slowdown:
            movement.x = 0
        else:
            movement.x -= slowdown
    elif movement.x < 0:
        if movement.x > -slowdown:
            movement.x = 0
        else:
            movement.x += slowdown

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        movement.x = -speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        movement.x = speed
    else: 
        interpolate(delta)
        
    move_and_slide(movement)
```

---

However, to better take advantage of the engine, consider using a `Tween`, for example:

```
extends KinematicBody

var speed : int = 10
var tween: Tween;
var movement = Vector3(0,0,0);

func _ready():
    tween = Tween.new();
    add_child(tween);

func update_movement(value: float):
    movement.x = value;

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        tween.interpolate_method(self, 'update_movement', -speed, 0, 0.833)
        tween.start()
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        tween.interpolate_method(self, 'update_movement', speed, 0, 0.833)
        tween.start()
    
    move_and_slide(movement)
```

That number 0.833 is the duration. After 0.833 seconds it will reach 0. *Originally you were reducing by 0.2 each frame starting from 10, which would take 50 frames. Assuming 60 frames per second, it would take 50/60 seconds to complete, that is aprox 0.833.*

Using `Tween`, you would not have to do these interpolations by hand, nor worry about frames or `delta`, just set the total time. Furthermore, if you see the documentation for [`interpolate_method`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html?highlight=interpolate_property#class-tween-method-interpolate-method) or the other methods in tween, you can see that it allows you to specify a [`TransitionType`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html?highlight=interpolate_property#enum-tween-transitiontype) and [`EaseType`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html?highlight=interpolate_property#enum-tween-easetype).

*Ah, yes, `Tween` is a node. It is the little sibling of `AnimationPlayer`, which you could use to animate any property… Thus, another option is to [export](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html) `movement`, create animations in an `AnimationPlayer` that animate (change over time) `movement`, and play them.*